# What is meaning of '#' before a variable in shell script?

Tags: shell

Can somebody please explain the what below piece of shell script would be doing?

```
END_POS=$((${#column}-$COLON_INDEX))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, it stands for the the length of the value of that variable:

```
$ v="hello"
$ echo ${#v}
5

$ v="bye"
$ echo ${#v}
3
```

So what does this command?

```
END_POS=$((${#column}-$COLON_INDEX))
```

It gets the length of the value in `$column` and substracts the value in `$COLON_INDEX` using the `$(( ))` syntax to perform arithmetic operations:

```
$ column="hello"
$ colon_index=2
$ r=$((${#column}-$colon_index))   # len("hello") - 2 = 5 - 2
$ echo $r
3
```

From [Arithmetic expression](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression):

> (( )) without the leading $ is not a standard sh feature. It comes
>   from ksh and is only available in ksh, Bash and zsh. $(( ))
>   substitution is allowed in the POSIX shell. As one would expect, the
>   result of the arithmetic expression inside the $(( )) is substituted
>   into the original command. Like for parameter substitution, arithmetic
>   substitution is subject to word splitting so should be quoted to
>   prevent it when in list contexts.

Comment: Surely the length of the value of the variable

Comment: @EdHeal errr true  : ) Updated

Answer (score 1):

All possible uses of `#` that I can think of:

It stands for the length of the variable's value or element in case of arrays:

I have echoed variable's value length, array length and array's 1st index element's length:

```
$ var="abcd"
$ echo "${#var}"
4
$ arr=('abcd' 'efg')
$ echo "${#arr[@]}"
2
$ echo "${#arr[1]}"
3
$
```

Also `$#` gives you the number of parameters passed to the script/function.